# Append a level to a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Say I have a pandas dataframe with three indices 'a', 'b' and 'c' - how can I add a fourth index from an array and set its name to 'd' at the same time?

This works:

```
df.set_index(fourth_index, append=True, inplace=True)
df.index.set_names(['a','b','c','d'], inplace=True)
```

But I'm looking for something that doesn't require me to also name the first three indices again, e.g. (this doesn't work):

```
df.set_index({'d': fourth_index}, append=True, inplace=True)
```

Am I missing some function here?

Answer (score 23):

Add `fourth_index` as a column and then call `set_index`. The name is preserved.

```
df = df.assign(d=fourth_index).set_index('d', append=True)
```

Note, if you're worried about memory, what you're doing is fine as is. No point sacrificing performance for a fewer characters.

---

**Demo**

```
df
          a   b   c   d
l1  l2                 
bar one  24  13   8   9
    two  11  30   7  23
baz one  21  31  12  30
    two   2   5  19  24
foo one  15  18   3  16
    two   2  24  28  11
qux one  23   9   6  12
    two  29  28  11  21

df.assign(l3=1).set_index('l3', append=True)

             a   b   c   d
l1  l2  l3                
bar one 1   24  13   8   9
    two 1   11  30   7  23
baz one 1   21  31  12  30
    two 1    2   5  19  24
foo one 1   15  18   3  16
    two 1    2  24  28  11
qux one 1   23   9   6  12
    two 1   29  28  11  21
```

Comment: Thanks! Not worried about performance - more worried about the fact I need to control the names of the other three columns in more than one place, I want to keep them as-is rather than having to re-define them to be the same they were before :-)

Comment: How can I specify the level at which the new index column is inserted? append=True always seems to insert the level after the last existing level column?

Comment: @Stefan seems like at least for inserting it at the left you can do it with `df.set_index(['new', df.index])`. For inserting at any position you could compile a new list out of the old index with the new one mixed in at the right positions.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just save the names of the previous values from before i.e.

```
old_names = df.index.names
df.set_index(fourth_index, append=True, inplace=True)
df.index.set_names(old_names + ['d'], inplace=True)
```

This then keeps the benefits of the good performance and doesn't require you to re-type the old names.

Answer (score 0):

set_names supports level-specific (re-)naming

```
df.set_index(fourth_index, append=True, inplace=True)
df.index.set_names('d', level=df.index.nlevels-1, inplace=True)
```

also possible in one line without inplace:

```
df.index = df.set_index(fourth_index, append=True).index.set_names('d', level=df.index.nlevels)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```py
fourth_index.name = 'd'
df.set_index(fourth_index, append=True, inplace=True)
```